# Can my work on manufacturing, designing & fabrication of an electric solar vehicle be considered as an original research & can it be published

Tags: publications, research-process, application

My classmates and I are pursuing B.Tech in Mechanical engineering and we have formed a team to manufacture, design, fabricate, and develop an electric solar vehicle which would operate under safe speed. We are designing it in a way to reduce weight and make it much lighter. We are also trying to minimise the cost of production &  making sure that it works both at day and night.

We have designed it using Solidworks and have taken into account all types of loads and stresses that will be generated. Apart from these goals, we are also working upon various other parameters which include efficiency and other considerations. We have fabricated the solar cells on our own.

We expect to complete our work in a couple of months. I want to know if our work can be claimed as an original research and if we can publish it. If so, how many people can be authors on the research paper ?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answers to your questions are that, yes, you can claim your work to be original research and you can have as many authors as you like.  That said, the fact you think your work is original and of publication quality does not guarantee that any journal will agree.  Your best bet is to discuss the specifics of your project with your advisor (I assume you have one?) and follow his/her advice.